# cakephp get element value js helper

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, helper

I am beginner to CakePHP and tried searching this question but no any gold.
I have a select button and when user select an option I have to fire a event and pass the selected value to the controller's action.
The code goes below:

---

```
<?php
//I only need a select button why to bother of creating form
echo $this->Form->input('district',array('label'=>'labelhere','id'=>'idhere'));

//script handler for select option
$this->Js->get('#idhere');
$this->Js->event(
        'change',
        $this->Js->request(
            array('action' => 'listing',<the selected value of #idhere here>),
            array('async' => true,
                'method'=>'POST',
                'update' => '#HFNames')
        )
    );

?>
<div id="HFNames">
Div to include ajax returns.
</div>
```

Precisely,
What is the CakePHP equivalent for Jquery's $('selector').value();

Here is the Html code generated:

```
<html>
<div class="input select"><label for="idhere">labelhere</label><select  name="data[district]" id="idhere">
<option value="01">Bhojpur</option>
<option value="02">Dhankuta</option>
<option value="03">Ilam</option>
<option value="04">Jhapa</option>
<option value="05">Khotang</option>
<option value="06">Morang</option>
<option value="07">Okhaldhunga</option>
<option value="08">Panchthar</option>
<option value="09">Sankhuwasabha</option>
<option value="10">Saptari</option>
<option value="11">Siraha</option>
</select></div>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Give the html source of the input.

Comment: which html is generated by `echo $this->Form->input('district',array('label'=>'labelhere','id'=>'idhere'));`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php
//I only need a select button why to bother of creating form
echo $this->Form->input('district',array('label'=>'labelhere','id'=>'idhere'));

//script handler for select option
$this->Js->get('#idhere');
$this->Js->event(
        'change',
        $this->Js->request(
            array('action' => 'listing'),
            array('async' => true,
                'method'=>'POST',
                'update' => '#HFNames',
                'data'   => '$("selector").value()')
        )
    );

?>
<div id="HFNames">
Div to include ajax returns.
</div>
```

make time to read this post: [Dynamic Web With Cake](http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2011/11/dynamic-select-box-with-cakephp-2-0/)

Comment: `var_dump($this->request->data)` in your `function listing` to see how data came.